# Display data in UI from link function angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to assigned a value to a $scope variable inside link function and this value has to be displayed in the UI.But, I am not able to display it on UI.

My code is as follows:

UI:

```
<div> {{articleContent}}</div>
```

Link function:

```
app.directive('member', function($compile,$http,getTocService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '=',
            articleDetails: '='
        },
        template: "<div><li ng-if='member.title'><a href='#' ng-click='getContent(member.itemId)'>{{member.title}}</a></li></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.getContent = function(itemId) {
                    getTocService.getArtData(itemId, function(data){
                        var articleDetails = data.data.getArticleResponse.articleDetail.articleContent;
    scope.$parent.articleContent = articleDetails;

                        alert(articleDetails);
                    });
                }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('apdController', function($scope, getTocService,$location) {
    var bookId = $location.search().id;
    var sampdata = getTocService.getToc(bookId);
    $scope.tasks =sampdata;
    $scope.articleContent = '';

});
```

I want to display articleContent variable's data . Can someone help me please..

Comment: what is `link`. is it a directive's link?

Comment: Yes. It is directive. I have updated the code now.

Comment: is `id="articleContent"` is a view of directive or your main html?

Comment: That is main html. I just used it as I was trying to do something with javascript. no need of id there..

Comment: so basically you want to display directive's `scope` variable in your main html. right?

Comment: @Abhilash . Yes. Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.getContent = function(itemId) {
      getTocService.getArtData(itemId, function(data){
            var articleDetails = data.data.getArticleResponse.articleDetail.articleContent;

            // Assign your's scope article content here
            scope.articleContent = articleDetails;
            alert(articleDetails);
      });
}
```

And your html should be look like this,

```
<member member="myMember" article-data="myData" article-content="articleContent"> </member>
<div> {{articleContent.content}}</div>
```

Comment: Its not displaying data on UI. no error on browser console too. Do I need to make any change in controller or html?